# soql in java to fetch the deleted records

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a scenario where I would like to fetch all the deleted records at salesforce end and send to UI using java.

I tried with the following SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate FROM Note ALL ROWS
```

I end up with response as:

```
[ {
  "message" : "ALL ROWS not allowed in this context",
  "errorCode" : "MALFORMED_QUERY"
} ]
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You need to use the queryAll call / endpoint instead of using ALL ROWS

Comment: @superfell: Thanks for the suggestion. queryAll did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The "ALL ROWS" option is only supported by Apex SOQL queries. You can't use it with REST calls or in the developer console.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008teaIAA

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have used queryAll call to get my things done.